# How to properly pass variables from a map() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, map-function

I have the following code which creates variables based on 2 different parts of JSON data.

```
function showDescription(implant) {
  return implant.description + '<br />';
}
function showSectionHeadings(implant) {
  return implant.sectionHeading + '<br />';
}
function loadImplantsOfFamily(implantFamily) {
  var implantData = JSON.parse(getLocal("implantData"));
  var allImplantsInFamily = implantData.implants.filter(familyToLoad,implantFamily);
  var implantDescription = allImplantsInFamily.map(showDescription);
  var sectionHeading = allImplantsInFamily.map(showSectionHeadings);
  var uniqueVals = sectionHeading.unique();
  $("#holderForImplants").html(uniqueVals);
}
```

It's all working fine, but the two functions I have are identical, except for the JSON key to which they refer. How do I combine these two functions into one, passing in the JSON variable from the map function?

Something like this doesn't work:

```
function showKey(implant,key) {
  return implant.key + '<br />';
}
function loadImplantsOfFamily(implantFamily) {
  var implantData = JSON.parse(getLocal("implantData"));
  var allImplantsInFamily = implantData.implants.filter(familyToLoad,implantFamily);
  var implantDescription = allImplantsInFamily.map(showKey("description"));
  var sectionHeading = allImplantsInFamily.map(showKey("sectionHeading"));
  var uniqueVals = sectionHeading.unique();
  $("#holderForImplants").html(uniqueVals);
}
```

Comment: Use `implant[key]`. `implant.key` literally tries to get the `key` property

Comment: Sorry @AndrewL., I should have said, I just made that last bit up, I could have easily typed `whatever` instead of `key`.

Comment: Thanks @Nirus, unfortunately I won't get a chance to test these solutions for a couple of hours, but once I do I'll definitely mark one as the solution. Cheers mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple to use closure like below:

```
function showKey(implant,key) {
   return function(elem, index, arr){ //Catch 'elem', 'index', 'arr' - Element passed by Map function. Checkout the documentation for more on this.
      return implant[key] + '<br />';
   } 
}
```

Simple example:

```
var a = {one:1, two:2}
var b = {three:3, four: 4};

var dynamic = function(obj, key){
  return function(el){ //Closure call to save the key. 'el' will be element injected from Map function
        console.log(obj[key])
      return obj[key];
   } 
}

var test = [1, 2, 3];
test.map(dynamic(b, "four"));
test.map(dynamic(a, "one"));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mdLda62f/

The closure function help you to save the dynamic key within the function reference so that the required value will be extracted at runtime. That's the beauty of javascript closure concept.

---

### Reference

Documentation on [Array.Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for more explaination of map function and its parameters

Comment: Why need a closure? `return implant[key] + '<br />';` seems just fine

Comment: OP is sending key dynamically. Array Map accepts the function reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bracket notation for object properties so that you can use a variable. Your function would look something like this:

```
function showDescription(implant, key) {
    return implant[key] + '<br />';
}
```

And then call it like:

```
showDescription(implant, 'description');
showDescription(implant, 'sectionHeading');
```

Comment: Looks like the OP is using `map`, so you have to return a function.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to combine this function, you can make use of closure and implement function in following way.

```
function showKey(prop){
  return function(obj){
    return obj[prop];
  };
}
```

At later stage just call, the `showKey` function as you have described in your code. The inner function will be called by `map`, by passing the element of array and the closure will ensure the appropriate property name to access.